Kotlin Multiplatform: error on sync The Default Kotlin Hierarchy Template was not applied
I try to sync and build a project in KMP but I have this error:
The Default Kotlin Hierarchy Template was not applied to 'project ':core'':
Explicit .dependsOn() edges were configured for the following source sets:
[iosArm64Main, iosArm64Test, iosMain, iosSimulatorArm64Main, iosSimulatorArm64Test, iosTest, iosX64Main, iosX64Test]

Consider removing dependsOn-calls or disabling the default template by adding
    'kotlin.mpp.applyDefaultHierarchyTemplate=false'
to your gradle.properties

I have a Mac whit M2 chip, this is build.gradle.kts file:
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "11"
            }
        }
    }
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "core"
            isStatic = true
        }
       pod("UICKeyChainStore")
       pod("FirebaseCore")
       pod("FirebaseInstanceID")
    }

    val coroutines = "1.8.0"
    val ktor = "2.3.9"

    sourceSets {
        all {
            languageSettings.optIn("kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
            languageSettings.optIn("kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCName")
        }

        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines")

                // Http
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.5.1")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktor")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:$ktor")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm:$ktor")
                implementation("com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.6.0")

                implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1")
                implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.4.1")
            }
        }
        val androidUnitTest by getting
        val androidInstrumentedTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)

            dependencies {
                // Http
                //implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:1.0-M1-1.4.0-rc")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.5.1")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor")
                //implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:1.3.2")
                //implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:1.3.2")
            }
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.****.****.core"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 23
        testOptions.targetSdk = 34
    }
    java {
        toolchain.languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
    }
    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KaptGenerateStubs> {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
}

any idea to fix this?

According to the Kotlin website here
remove this section of your code
 val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)

            dependencies {
                // Http
                //implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:1.0-M1-1.4.0-rc")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.5.1")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor")
                //implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:1.3.2")
                //implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:1.3.2")
            }
        }

and replace with this
iosMain.dependencies {
            implementation("***************")
        }

